# Android create a collection which automatic sort new item when add

Tags: android, sorting, collections, priority-queue

Hi i have and android app with model `TopStory`. I want create a collection of `TopStory` (topStories) which order the item by value (ie.time) Whenever new item is added. the new added item will be at the correct index (order by value time) (ie: create an already sorted Collection so that whenever we add new item, it will automatically be inserted to the right position)

Here is my model

```
public class TopStory {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int score;
    private JSONArray kids;
    private long time;
    private String url;

    public TopStory() {
    }

    public TopStory(int id, String title, String author, int point, long time,String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.score = point;
        this.time = time;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

What should I use? `PriorityQueue, TreeMap`,...? how to create that type of collection? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: see `java.util.Collections#binarySearch`

Comment: hi binarySearch is use to search value to find its index? but we want to created an already sorted collection?

Comment: it returns: `the non-negative index of the element, or a negative index which is the -index - 1 where the element would be inserted`

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeMap data structure http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html

Find how it will work for you,

http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treemap/comparator-user-object/

```
TreeMap<Empl,String> tm = new TreeMap<Empl, String>(new MyNameComp());

tm.put(new Empl("Ram",3000), "RAM");
tm.put(new Empl("John",6000), "JOHN");
tm.put(new Empl("Crish",2000), "CRISH");
tm.put(new Empl("Tom",2400), "TOM");

Set<Empl> keys = tm.keySet();
for(Empl key:keys){
    System.out.println(key+" ==> "+tm.get(key));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can we change the String parameter to something that it more suitable with List of object (for example lists of model topStories)?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question right, you have an object, and you want to sort it into a data structure based on an integer property. In this case I recommend implementing a binary tree.

Comment: Sorry a bit unclear. My question is to create an already sorted Collection so that whenever we add new item, it will automatically be inserted to the right position. can binaryTree access item base on index?

Comment: If you implement the algorithm correctly, inserting an object into a binaryTree will put it in between the next largest and next smallest object,

Comment: but the problem is that binaryTree does not support accessing item by index number (ie. position while in recycleView). We need to stick to List

Comment: You can traverse the tree until you get to the index number by using an iterator.

Comment: but if how can we access and index to retrieve date when in adapter of RecycleView? (lilke List.get(position))?

Comment: Write a function that returns the relevant value, for example public void String (view view){ //iterate through the binary tree until it finds the correct index};

Comment: can explain as an example I have a collection as data source for recycleview. In recycle adapter. I want access it value by position? seem can only get with List Collection type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110115/discussion-between-user1375469-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh then use `Collections#binarySearch` and you will be able to use `List#add(int location, E object)` method

Comment: thanks, do you have an example on this implementation?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh implementation of what? just call `binarySearch` and use its result for computing the index when calling `add` method

Comment: you mean we calculate the index before add? I tried to but have error. is this correct: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit

Comment: again: read what `binarySearch` returns and what is accepted by `add` method